# Conditionally show a value from a row that has a cell in it with a matching value

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, gnumeric

I am trying to find an Excel (or LibreOffice or Gnumeric) formula that would make a cell show the value from column B using some row which is determined by the value in the cell next to the formula-based cell. For example, if the cell next to the formula was "name03", the formula should be replaced with "0.83".

It would be even better if instead of using Column A, it found that the correct Column was A, using the column name, eg. Column with label "Names".

I am not looking for VBA or macros, just standard spreadsheet equations.

```
Column A    B       C       D   

Names,  Scores, Date,   Comments
name01, 0.95,   20141105,   "NA"
name02, 0.92,   20141105,   "NA"
name03, 0.83,   20141105,   "NA"
name04, 0.81,   20141105,   "NA"
name05, 0.70,   20141105,   "NA"
name06, 0.70,   20141105,   "NA"
```

elsewhere (probably in a different sheet):

```
name03, =WHAT_FORMULA??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in sheet2, and your formula is in cell B2 of sheet2, use this

```
=vlookup(A2,sheet1!$A$2:$D$10,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how's this, I set up a search criteria area with:

```
             I               J
  1     SearchInHeader     Names
  2     RowLabel           name03
  3     ReturnFromColumn   Scores
  4     ReturnedValue      0.83
```

the formula in "J4" is:

```
  =INDEX(INDIRECT(J3),MATCH(J2,INDIRECT(J1),0))
```

The trick is to set up each column as a named range. So, you would have named ranges called "Names", "Scores", "Date", and "Comments". I included all the columns just to be complete.
So the named range "Names" is =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7 etc. NOTE: the named ranges start with row "2" NOT "1".

So, the formula uses INDIRECT(J1) to pick the relevant named range, then finds the value in J2 in that named range (MATCH) and then passes that row number to the INDEX function to pull out the value in the column designated by INDIRECT(J3) that corresponds with that row.

So, as you asked it dynamically determines the correct column to pull from, finds the row label in that column, and then (you didn't ask for this part) dynamically determines, as specified in the search criteria, what column is labeled as the "ReturnFromColumn" and has the value that should be returned.